RABBITMQ: changing default user and password using .conf file
I am trying to change default user and password using following rabbitmq.conf file:
default_vhost = /
default_user = newuser
default_pass = somepassword
default_permissions.configure = .*
default_permissions.read = .*
default_permissions.write = .*
default_user_tags.administrator = true
default_user_tags.management = true
disk_free_limit.absolute = 5GB
consumer_timeout = 18000000
vm_memory_high_watermark.absolute = 1GB


Rabbit logs are saying that configuration is applied:
rabbitmq-server[34731]:   Config file(s): /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

I tried changing vm_memory_high_watermark.absolute to new value and it was applied after service restart, so configuration file is ok.
But i still was able log in management plugin only using 'guest' user.
When i was trying to use credentials from config file it failed to authorize.
I checked if there are any other users created - only guest user exists.
So i tried:

to delete guest user also, suggesting default user might be created on restart -> after this i still was not able to log in with 'guest' or 'newuser'
to reinstall rabbitmq, suggesting default user might be created on the first service start -> i'm still unable to log in with 'newuser', only with 'guest'.

I know that i can create new user with rabbitmqctl and then delete the guest, but i want to to it using config.

You probably have to edit your advanced.config and definitions.json as well to add more details and the hash of your password. For which you will eventually have to use rabbitmqctl. Or you can also try to change it via the HTTP api.
